# Iterate over two arrays looking up values in a dict

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, vectorization

So I have a dictionary:

```
LCM_SCS = { 
        (1, "A"): 36, (1, "B"): 60, (1, "C"): 73, (1, "D"): 79, 
        (2, "A"): 36, (2, "B"): 60, (2, "C"): 73, (2, "D"): 79, 
        (3, "A"): 74, (3, "B"): 83, (3, "C"): 88, (3, "D"): 90, 
        (4, "A"): 68, (4, "B"): 79, (4, "C"): 86, (4, "D"): 89, 
        (5, "A"): 30, (5, "B"): 58, (5, "C"): 71, (5, "D"): 78, 
        (6, "A"): 39, (6, "B"): 61, (6, "C"): 74, (6, "D"): 80, 
        (7, "A"): 39, (7, "B"): 61, (7, "C"): 74, (7, "D"): 80, 
        (8, "A"): 39, (8, "B"): 61, (8, "C"): 74, (8, "D"): 80, 
        (10, "A"): 30, (10, "B"): 48, (10, "C"): 65, (10, "D"): 73,
```

I also have two arrays that combined give the tuple key for my dictionary above:

Array 1:

```
array1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
          [2, 2, 3],
          [2, 4, 5]])
```

Array 2:

```
array2 = np.array([["A", "A", "A"],
             ["B", "B", "B"],
             ["C", "C", "C"]])
```

My code is:

```
Numbers = np.empty_like(array1)


for [x, y], (value1, value2) in np.ndenumerate(izip(array1, array2)):
        CN_numbers[x, y] = LCM_SCS.get((value1, value2))

    return Numbers
```

This code doesn't work. What I want to get is an array that looks like this:

```
Numbers = array([[36, 36, 36],
          [60, 60, 83],
          [73, 86, 71]])
```

So essentially I have two arrays containing the values to use as the key for my lookup dict and I am not sure how to implement this in code.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick

Solution using vectorise:

```
a_new = np.empty_like(array1)

def get_CN_numbers(a1, a2):
    return LCM_SCS[(a1, a2)]  # your basic scalar-operation

V_get_CN = np.vectorize(get_CN_numbers)

a_new = V_get_CN(array1, array2)

print a_new
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) it.

```
@numpy.vectorize
def get_CN_numbers(a1, a2):
    return LCM_SCS[(a1,a2)]  # your basic scalar-operation

get_CN_numbers(array1, array2)
=>
array([[36, 36, 36],
       [60, 60, 83],
       [73, 86, 71]])
```

In general, using `vectorize` is an easy way to extend scalar-operations (in your case, getting a value from a dict by a scalar key) to work on arrays (in your case, two arrays of keys).  As you already found out, the tricky part, which `vectorize` takes care of for you, is maintaining the shape.

This provides simplicity, but not necessarily speed, because `vectorize` is implemented using python-space loops.

Comment: Hi, this sounds seems like a really easy solution but I cant seem to get it to work. I get the error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'"

Comment: Thanks! this will make later things I have to do easier.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> new_array = np.rec.fromarrays((array1,array2),names='x,y')     # This will generate all keys that you'll look value for.
>>> print new_array
[[(1, 'A') (1, 'A') (1, 'A')]
 [(2, 'B') (2, 'B') (3, 'B')]
 [(2, 'C') (4, 'C') (5, 'C')]]
>>> result = np.zeros([3,3],dtype=int)      #Having issue to modify directly on new_array so I initialized a new numpy array to store result
>>> for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(new_array):
    result[x][y] = LCM_SCS[tuple(value)]

>>> print result
[[36 36 36]
 [60 60 83]
 [73 86 71]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LCM_SCS = { 
        (1, "A"): 36, (1, "B"): 60, (1, "C"): 73, (1, "D"): 79, 
        (2, "A"): 36, (2, "B"): 60, (2, "C"): 73, (2, "D"): 79, 
        (3, "A"): 74, (3, "B"): 83, (3, "C"): 88, (3, "D"): 90, 
        (4, "A"): 68, (4, "B"): 79, (4, "C"): 86, (4, "D"): 89, 
        (5, "A"): 30, (5, "B"): 58, (5, "C"): 71, (5, "D"): 78, 
        (6, "A"): 39, (6, "B"): 61, (6, "C"): 74, (6, "D"): 80, 
        (7, "A"): 39, (7, "B"): 61, (7, "C"): 74, (7, "D"): 80, 
        (8, "A"): 39, (8, "B"): 61, (8, "C"): 74, (8, "D"): 80, 
        (10, "A"): 30, (10, "B"): 48, (10, "C"): 65, (10, "D"): 73}

array1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]).tolist()
array2 = np.array([["A", "A", "A"], ["B", "B", "B"], ["C", "C", "C"]]).tolist()

array1 = [y for sub in array1 for y in sub]
array2 = [y for sub in array2 for y in sub]
results = [LCM_SCS[(array1[k], array2[k])] for k in range(len(array1))]
```

**Output:**

```
[36, 36, 36, 60, 60, 83, 73, 86, 71]
```

You can convert this to a list of lists as desired, and even make it a `np.array()`.

Comment: Thanks but the output your result generates is not what I am looking for. I want to maintain the shape of the array just with the new values from the dictionary.